# Why is this panda chasing XP-tan?

Tags: os-tan

I've had this image of [XP-tan's final days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EquY.jpg) for a while (it's a tall image thus the link). after XP-tan sees 98-tan being taken away bellow that there is a frame of XP-Tan being chased by a panda.

What is this references supposed to be? why is XP-tan being harassed by a panda?

Comment: I vote for migration to Super User ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the panda is an icon of "Fujacks" and used as a symbol of computer virus in this image.
(She is suffered from a wide variety of viruses.)
It is a virus software which changes desktop icons to pandas or golden pigs.
See also page 5 of [Symantec's report](https://www.symantec.com/avcenter/reference/ThePandaOutlaw.pdf).